# Capturing part of a url

Tags: regex

I'm having some difficulty writing a regular expression. My input will be a url, looking like this:

`http://www.a.com/farms/important-stuff-here#ignorable-stuff`

I wanted to capture (some-stuff-here), which is everything between the last forward slash, and the first # sign (or just the ending, if the # sign extra content does not exist. I thought this might do it:

`(http://www.a.com/farms/)`
`([anything but a # character]*)`
`(.*)`

I'm not sure how to express the 2nd group (`[anything but a # character]*`).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Anything but" is called a negated character class, and, in your case, is spelled

```
[^#]
```

Your regex would be

```
http://www.a.com/farms/([^#]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

For most re engines you probably want `[^#]` (the `^` negates a character class).

Answer (score 0):

depending on your language, you might want to use modules/libraries that can parse url nicely for you. eg in PHP, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = "http://www.a.com/farms/important-stuff-here#ignorable-stuff";
$parsed = parse_url($url);
print $parsed['path'];
```

with Python, [urlparse()](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) eg:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s=""http://www.a.com/farms/important-stuff-here#ignorable-stuff"
>>> urlparse.urlparse(s).path
'/farms/important-stuff-here'
```

IF you really want to do it by hand, first replace everything from "#" onwards, then replace everything from the start till "/"

```
$ echo "http://www.a.com/farms/important-stuff-here#ignorable-stuff" | sed 's/#.*//;s|.*\/||'
important-stuff-here
```

Or using just plain splits on strings

```
$url = "http://www.a.com/farms/important-stuff-here#ignorable-stuff";
$s = explode("#",$url,2);
$t = explode("/",$s[0]);
print end($t);
```

Comment: won't the path() also include "farm/" ? I just want [important-stuff-here], thank you.

Comment: that's easy to fix. explode/split on "/" and get the right item. I will let you do that yourself.